# Kafkajs Producer Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

i have this producer

```
const { Kafka } = require("kafkajs");

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: "app",
  brokers: ["localhost:29092"],
});

async function sendMessageOnProducer() {
  const producer = kafka.producer();
  await producer.connect();
  await producer.send({
    topic: "test",
    messages: [
      {
        value: "hello",
      },
    ],
  });
  producer.disconnect();
}

sendMessageOnProducer();
```

and i have this docker compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: cluster
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

but when i run my producer i have this error

{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-05-30T14:58:26.187Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:29092","retryCount":5,"retryTime":6966}

i'm trying to send a payload to my kafka

Comment: Is your node code running in its own container?

Comment: You're missing a `KAFKA_LISTENERS` variable

Comment: i added the KAFKA_LISTENERS variable but i have the same error @OneCricketeer

Comment: no i run it with npm start

Comment: What did you set it to? It needs to be `KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092`; Also, 1) there is no `test` topic being created anywhere 2) The Kafka Container is not immediately available. You should add a sleep in your JS code or the npm script

Comment: yes i added it like that and i created my topic when i run : docker exec kafka kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --list , i see the topic name that i added @OneCricketeer

Comment: Okay. Great. As mentioned, container doesn't start immediately. Try adding sleep before connecting from KafkaJS.

Comment: i add this and i can't connect to my kafka :   await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); @OneCricketeer

Comment: Are you sure Kafka container actually started? Your Zookeeper container is called cluster, but you never use that. See working file, which is also linked in the duplicate post https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-single.yml#L7